# How to stop printing if the value is the same than the previous one in a while cycle

Tags: python, file, printing, while-loop, cycle

The following code will show the name of the newest file created in a folder and its content, and will also keep printing every 30 seconds.

```
import glob    
import os      
import time

while True: 

 newest=max(glob.iglob('/Users/BetaBrawler/Downloads/HernanVillela/*'), key=os.path.getctime)

 print newest     
 file = open(newest,'r')     
 texto = [x.strip() for x in file.readlines()]

 print texto     
 time.sleep(30)
```

The only thing I would like to do is that the console stops printing if the following output has the same value as the previous one (same file and its contents) and only printing if a new file is created in a folder.

Answer (score 0):

```
import glob
import os
import time

oldfile = None
while True:
    newest = max(glob.glob('/Users/BetaBrawler/Downloads/HernanVillela/*'), key=os.path.getctime)

    if newest == oldfile:
        time.sleep(30)
        continue

    oldfile = newest
    with open(newest) as infile:
        print [line.strip() for line in infile]
    time.sleep(30)
```

Comment: This refactor changes several behaviors of the original script:

1. It does not sleep for 30 seconds if the file has not changed. The effect is that when the file does not change, the contents will print very rapidly until a new file is found.

2. Each line of the file will no longer be `strip`ped.

3. I think `newest = oldfile` should probably be `newest == oldfile` for this to work properly.

Comment: @theunraveler: thank you for the bugreports. I guess I'm having an off day. I've fixed them all, now

Comment: @theunraveler The code works good, but it only prints the contents of the last file created. Should I add or remove something to also print the name of the file?

Comment: @Beta: `print newest` would do that

Answer (score 0):

```
import glob    
import os      
import time

current = None

while True: 
   newest = max(glob.iglob('/Users/BetaBrawler/Downloads/HernanVillela/*'), key=os.path.getctime)

   if newest != current:
       current = newest
       print newest     
       with open(newest, 'r') as file_:
           texto = [x.strip() for x in file_.readlines()]
           print texto

   time.sleep(30)
```